# Connecting to mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my following tutorial code from "Learning PHP MYSQL and Javascript" by OReilly.

```
<?php 
//require_once = 'login.php';

$db_database = 'publications';
$db_hostname = 'localhost:8888';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'root';


$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MYSQL: ". mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to connect to database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = $mysql_query($query);

if(!$result) die ("Could not query: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
    echo 'Author: ' . mysql_result($result, $j, 'author') . '</br>';
    echo 'Title: ' . mysql_result($result, $j, 'title'). '</br>';
    echo 'ISBN: '.mysql_result($result, $j, 'isbn').'</br>';
}

?>
```

However, I'm getting an error when trying to connect. The browser says it's a 500 error (which really isn't that helpful). When I take out the lines `$db_username = 'root'; $db_password = 'root';` I get another error saying: "Unable to connect to database: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'publications'".

Can anyone help diagnose the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is root really your root password or are you just putting that there for example's sake? I should also add - have you ever successfully connected to this db?

Comment: Do you have the username, password set to root?

Comment: In case of fatal errors (500) raise the error_level in the php.ini and/or look into the webservers `error.log`.

Comment: Even though most beginner tutorials tell you to, it's actually a bad idea to display the mysql_errors() because it can give attackers information about your database that they could exploit.  I'll usually build some sort of developer mode into my applications.  Something like setting a `dev_mode = false` at the top of my database include and then testing for `dev_mode` before displaying an error message `if(!$result) die ("Database error" . (dev_mode === true ? mysql_error() : ''));` Better yet, store dev_mode in a `session` object and only set it through a password protected page.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this

```
$result = $mysql_query($query);
```

to this

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Function name is `mysql_query` not `$mysql_query`, `$` is used in variable names.

Also, instead of trying to "see" your code immediately in a browser window you could use a PHP command line instead. If your file is called `foo.php` you coudl do:

```
>> php foo.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: mysql_query in /var/www/foo.php on line 17
PHP Fatal error:  Function name must be a string in /var/www/foo.php on line 17
```

As you see, the error message is pretty clear. Because of using `$mysql_query` it thinks that `mysql_query` is a variable, but such a variable is not defined somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Do you try connecting manually to your db by connection infor u set up in code,

use phpmysql to connect to db first , change phpmysql config file to match the mysql server authentication infor, then ensure all are right before coding anything further.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like below:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$conn)
    {
        die("Connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conn,"Database_name");
    if(!$db)
    {
        echo "Connection failed";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please write this

```
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
```

instead of

```
mysql_select_db($db_database)
```

And write this

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

instead of

```
$result = $mysql_query($query);
```

One more thing please check your host name :`$db_hostname = 'localhost:8888';`

By general it is `$db_hostname = 'localhost:8080';`

So please confirm one more time

Answer (score 0):

`$` symbol should be used only for variables not for functions

```
$var=5;// variable declaration
```

if you want to declare function syntax $ should not be used 
Ex:

```
$function_var = mysql_query($query);
```

In this `function_var` is variable and `mysql_query($query)` is function.

Comment: This does not add much to other answers.

Answer (score 0):

### Stop using [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)!

You should **not** use this or other related functions related to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension.

It's depreciated and removed in PHP 7.0.0 and beyond.
An alternative is using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).
Below is an example script for connecting to MySQL using PDO:

```
<?php

  /* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */

  /* DSN options:
     http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

     Error handling options:
     http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

     Learn how to secure against SQL injection attacks:
     http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
  */

  $user = 'myusername';
  $pass = 'mypassword';
  $host = 'localhost';
  $mydb = 'mydatabase';

  $dsn = "mysql:dbname=$mydb;host=$host"; 

  try {
      $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

?>
```