# HTML/PHP Form Problems

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm relatively new to web coding, but I know quite a bit, I was making a registration form earlier, which also checks if the fields are empty. It comes up OK, but nothing seems to work, when the fields are empty, the message doesn't come up, and when the fields are fine, it just loads but doesn't actually insert it into the database. Also, once I press the submit button, the form just disappears as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<form method="post">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $password=md5(hash("sha512",$password));
    if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
        $message="Please enter information into the fields.";
    } else {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('',$username,$password)");
        $message="Register successful!";
    }
    echo "<div id='box>$message</div>";
}
?>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions, it will be deprecated soon. And you have to `escape` the inputs from the user's input.

Comment: Thanks, how do i do that?

Comment: read this: http://in2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: just change `$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);` http://in2.php.net/mysql_escape_string    But i suggest to use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not printing out `mysql` errors, you just need to add `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of the query as in my example i did. Anyway you should surround your strings with `quotes`. The page came out blank when you press because if condition is met. So change as follow

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('','$username','$password')") or die(mysql_error());
```

As side note i would stop using `mysql_` function since they are derecated and use instead either [**`PDO`**](https://www.php.net/PDO) or [**`mysqli`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with prepared statements to avoid any risk of mysql injections since your code is highly vulnerable. [**LEARN MORE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

As `CodeBird` correctly stated

> md5 of an empty string will return a 32 chars string, so the password you are testing will never be empty

Comment: You should add that md5 of an empty string, returns a 32 chars string, so actually the password he's testing is never empty

Comment: Hi, I changed the query but I am getting the error of 'No Database Selected' - however, this is my connect code, what is wrong with it?
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","follow");

Comment: So you are not connected to database, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326696/connecting-to-mysql-using-php

Comment: So add the second part about `mysql_select_db`

Answer (score 1):

Change the query statement to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('','$username','$password')");
```

Start using mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* as the latter are deprecated

Answer (score 1):

```
check this out "(`id`, `username`, `password`)" example column name use what you have made it.
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    enter code here
    if(empty($username) || empty($password)){
        $message="Please enter information into the fields.";
    } else {
        $password=md5(hash("sha512",$password));
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES('','$username','$password');");
        $message="Register successful!";
    }
    echo "<div id='box'>".$message."</div>";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is wrong, use:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES('data1', 'data2' )
```

Or you can use

```
INSERT INTO tablename SET col1 = "data1", col2 = "data2"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue because you are misusing **[empty()](https://www.php.net/empty)**

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE

Also you should use double-pipes `||` for *or* in your `if()`

**This:**

```
if(empty($username) or empty($password)){
```

**Should be:**

```
if($username === '' || $password === ''){
```

Comment: Hi, I just did that, and tried it but as I said in the question, the area is going blank, so still no error message, is there any way to solve this?