# Use mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sql query that i want to use in php

```
 SET @sql = NULL;
            SELECT
              GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                CONCAT(
                  'max(CASE WHEN ca.date = ''',
                  date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                  ''' THEN coalesce(p.status, ''P'') END) AS `',
                  date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
                )
              ) INTO @sql
            FROM calendar
            where date>='2013-06-01'
              and date <= '2013-06-05';

        SET @sql 
          = CONCAT('SELECT ca.studentname,
                      ca.rollno,
                      ca.class, ', @sql, ' 
                    from
                    (
                      select c.date, a.studentname, a.rollno, a.class
                      from calendar c
                      cross join tbl_admission a
                    ) ca
                    left join tbl_absentees p
                      on ca.rollno = p.rollno
                      and ca.date = p.date
                    where ca.date>=''2013-06-01''
                      and ca.date <= ''2013-06-05''
                    group by ca.studentname, ca.rollno, ca.class
                    order by ca.rollno');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding or code conversion service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: What do you mean by `how to convert mysql query to php query`?

Comment: you need connect to database by `mysqli` or `PDO` and run the query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326696/connecting-to-mysql-using-php

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL PREPARE and EXECUTE statements are supported only within a MySQL stored program. For example, a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.

To run a MySQL query from PHP, you'd need to choose a database library to use (either mysqli or PDO), and your PHP code needs to establish a connection to a MySQL server. The patterns for preparing a SQL statement, executing it, and fetching results (for a SELECT) are similar for both libraries, but the syntax is a bit different. (Syntax also depends on whether you are writing object oriented style, or procedure oriented style.)

---

The MySQL code you posted is very odd.

- assign a NULL to a user-defined variable @sql
- execute a SELECT statement to populate udv @sql
- assign the result of a CONCAT function to the same udv @sql
- call PREPARE and EXECUTE to dynamically execute statement
- close the prepared statement before fetching any results

---

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

In PHP

- connect to the database
- prepare the first SELECT statement
- execute the statement
- fetch a row, store the returned value into a PHP variable
- close the statement
- use PHP string concatenation operations to string together another SQL statement into a PHP variable
- prepare the SQL statement from the contents of the PHP variable
- execute the SQL statement
- fetch some rows (? this step is not seen in the MySQL example)
- close the statement

Answer (score 0):

Better create a stored procedure in MySQL database with that sql code and then simply call that procedure via php.